# Windows 8 store app pin lock

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-8.1

I'm currently building a Windows 8 store app used on tablets, which has a custom pin lock mechanism. The data in the app is sensitive, so when it falls into the wrong hands the app should be locked. Now I also want to make the app go back to the login screen as soon as the app is not the active foreground app, so when you reopen it it is locked and the user has to re-enter his pin code. Same goes for when the tablets switches off the screen to save energy.

How do I achieve this?